# R loop to do calculation based on condition from another column

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have a data frame which looks like this

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfIy2.png]

Based on column V1, if the input in V1 = 1, it will be assigned to the treatment group and I will therefore take the result of column Yi(1), if the input in V1 = 0, I will take the result of Yi(0).

Ultimately, I need to do this for all 6 columns, V1 to V6. I have done it on V1, but have trouble expanding the function, could a for-loop do the job? My ultimate aim is to input and store all the diff into a data frame.

```
    t_group <- which(combined_df$V1>0)
c_group <- which(combined_df$V1<=0)

diff <- mean(combined_df$`Yi(1)`[t_group]) - mean(combined_df$`Yi(0)`[c_group])
diff
```

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Yi0 =  runif(n=10, min = 0, max = 100),
                 Yi1 = runif(n=10, min = 0, max = 100),
                 V1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                 V2 = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1))
df
#>         Yi0      Yi1 V1 V2
#> 1  96.92925 78.60610  1  0
#> 2  13.11842 30.26470  1  1
#> 3  57.02284 60.18323  1  0
#> 4  38.96841 51.58151  1  1
#> 5  41.48591 47.38174  1  0
#> 6  91.79000 89.82191  0  1
#> 7  41.61315 25.03463  0  0
#> 8  64.37319 29.87603  0  1
#> 9  10.10971 14.97266  0  0
#> 10 52.21190 52.87794  0  1
```

Apply your logic as a function to work on one column:

```
pm <- function(x) {
  as.numeric(
    ifelse(
      test = df[,x] == 0,
      yes = df[,"Yi1"],
      no = ifelse(
        test = df[,x] == 1,
        yes = df[,"Yi0"],
        no = "error")))
  }
```

Apply that function to all columns of interest:

```
ab <- sapply(X = 3:4, FUN=pm)
ab
#>            [,1]      [,2]
#>  [1,] 51.980213  8.064173
#>  [2,] 30.616215 30.616215
#>  [3,] 94.817918 34.882479
#>  [4,] 99.261267 99.261267
#>  [5,] 32.276397 60.470493
#>  [6,] 13.596881 81.908181
#>  [7,]  2.975445  2.975445
#>  [8,] 56.496649 43.317387
#>  [9,] 56.218272 56.218272
#> [10,] 93.022714  1.478989
```

`X` is a vector of column numbers for V1 to V6 and `FUN` is the function where your logic is defined.

Calculate difference of means:

```
mean(ab[,1]) - mean(ab[,2])
#> [1] 11.20691
```

### Edit

Calculate difference between means within the same column:

```
pm2 <- function(x) {
  mean(df[df[,x]==1,"Yi1"]) - mean(df[df[,x]==0,"Yi0"])
}

sapply(3:4,pm2)
```

Comment: I have modified the code to be like this, pm <- function(x) {
  a = ifelse(df[,x] == 0, df[,"Yi1"],
  b = ifelse(df[,x] == 1, df[,"Yi0"]))
  mean(a) - mean(b)      
}

sapply(X = 5:6, FUN=pm), but it will show me this error "Error in ifelse(df[, x] == 0, df[, "Yi1"], b = ifelse(df[, x] == 1, df[, : unused argument (b = ifelse(df[, x] == 1, df[, "Yi0"]))", how could I fix this?

Comment: Don't assign `b`. `pm` is one big `ifelse()` statement, so the result can only be assigned to one variable. Using `sapply()` with `pm` means you can apply it to multiple columns (as specified in `X=`). This essentially generates a new dataset where you can apply your pairwise mean difference calculation.

Comment: thank you for the response! but I need the mean of Yi1 within that column (12 from V1) to subtract the mean of Yi0 within the same column (the other 12 from V0), can I modify the pm function in this case?

Comment: My apologies for misunderstanding your question. I've updated my answer based on your comment; please let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Hi! I managed to figure this out thanks to your insights! Apologies for the late reply

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` you can try this:

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(Yi0 =  1:10,
                 Yi1 = 21:30,
                 V1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                 V2 = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1))
```

**Code**

```
df %>%
  summarise(across(V1:V2, 
                ~ mean(df %>% 
                         filter(.x == 1) %>%
                         pull(Yi1), na.rm = T) -
                  mean(df %>% 
                         filter(.x == 0) %>%
                         pull(Yi0), na.rm = T)))
```

For your data you may edit `V1:V2` to `V1:V6`.
**Output**

```
  V1 V2
1 15 21
```

Comment: Hi! this method seems like it would work, but my R console has been prompting "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used", it also thinks an extremely long time to run, is there any way I could fix this issue?